# Need to merge multiple sets of columns to 1 set of columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet on Google Drive that is capturing data from a form into multiple sets of columns with the same name.  I need to be able to merge all of the sets of columns into one set of columns.

I am using Google Forms to capture RSVPs for a family camp and ask the attendees for First Name, Last Name, Meals Attending, and Age in multiple fields.  This produces a spreadsheet with multiple sets of columns with these titles:

<kbd>First Name</kbd><kbd>Last Name</kbd><kbd>Meals attending</kbd><kbd>Age</kbd>

I don't know any vba but I need to combine all of the sets of columns into one set on a separate sheet.  This can be done in Google Sheets (preferred) or in Excel.  Does anyone know of a way that I can gather this data?

Edit:
I want to turn something like this:

<kbd>John</kbd><kbd>Smith</kbd><kbd>Saturday Breakfast, Saturday Lunch, Sunday Breakfast</kbd><kbd>15 and up</kbd><kbd>Jane</kbd><kbd>Smith</kbd><kbd>Saturday Breakfast, Saturday Lunch, Sunday Breakfast</kbd><kbd>15 and up</kbd>

Into:

<kbd>John</kbd><kbd>Smith</kbd><kbd>Saturday Breakfast, Saturday Lunch, Sunday Breakfast</kbd><kbd>15 and up</kbd>
<kbd>Jane</kbd><kbd>Smith</kbd><kbd>Saturday Breakfast, Saturday Lunch, Sunday Breakfast</kbd><kbd>15 and up</kbd>

Comment: use the CONCAT Function.More Info: http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/Productivity/GoogleConcatenate.aspx

Comment: Thanks neophyte for the input.  That's not quite what I'm looking for though, see my edit for a visual explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a script [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h3iNTuTO2YRBcYgX1SdSgmAgMebzsfdpPIQ2U4zodUI/edit) that works for me once copied into Script editor... and saved, then something like:

```
=vmerge(A1:D3,E1:H3,I1:L30,M1:P30)
```

Script:

```
function VMerge() { //Vertical Merge 2.12 (release candidate) - ahab facit 2010
  var maxw=0;
  var l=0;
  var minw=Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var al=arguments.length ;
  for( i=0 ; i<al ; i++){
    if( arguments[i].constructor == Array ) {
       l =arguments[i][0].length ; 
       maxw=l>maxw?l:maxw; minw=l<minw?l:minw; 
    }
    else if ((arguments[i] != "???") && (arguments[i].length!=0) ){ 
            l = 1 ;  // literal values count as array with a width of one cell, empty cells are ignored!
            maxw=l>maxw?l:maxw; minw=l<minw?l:minw;
         }                                                              
  }

  if( maxw==minw) { // when largest width equals smallest width all are equal /
    var s = new Array();
    for( i=0 ; i<al ; i++){
      if( arguments[i].constructor == Array ) s = s.concat( arguments[i].slice() )
      else if ((arguments[i] != "???") && (arguments[i].length!=0)) s = s.concat( [[arguments[i]]] )
    }
    if ( s.length == 0 ) return null ; else return s     
  }
  else return "#N/A: All data ranges must be of equal width!!"   
}
```

Comment: pnuts, that is very close to what I want and will do quite nicely.  The negatives of that script are that it does not exclude blank rows and having to input the column letters manually rather than some lookup or search function but I don't know that there's a way around that.  It will leave me with some work to do but much less than I would have otherwise had I think.  Thanks!